# Vb.net 2010 connectivity with MS Access 2007

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am using a form having 10 text boxes,1 register button & 1 exit button. I have created the database in MS Access 2007 and saved the file in desktop. I have connected by "Add New Data Source". Provider & Path is:**Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sipl\Desktop\Cust_Dtl.mdb**. But when I click register the following error is showing:

```
con.Open() - Doesn't have a valid file name.
```

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\sipl\Desktop\Cust_Dtl.mdb" & System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "Cust_Dtl.mdb"
    Dim insertcmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = constring
    insertcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    insertcmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES ('{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}')", "Table1", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox8.Text, TextBox9.Text, TextBox10.Text)
    insertcmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    Try
        insertcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Please help to fix this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the database string twice:

```
 Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\sipl\Desktop\Cust_Dtl.mdb" & System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "Cust_Dtl.mdb"
```

This gives the string "C:\Users\sipl\Desktop\Cust_Dtl.mdbC:\Users\sipl\Desktop\Cust_Dtl.mdb"

Remove either `C:\Users\sipl\Desktop\Cust_Dtl.mdb"`

or `& System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "Cust_Dtl.mdb`